# How to determine that the date is included in a particular month and to join the tables?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the first table which stores hourly information about the status of the object.

```
| TIME_KEY            | ID_OBJECT | STATUS |
|---------------------|-----------|--------|
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 1         | IN     |
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2         | OUT    |
| 2018-01-01 01:00:00 | 1         | OUT    |
| 2018-01-01 01:00:00 | 2         | IN     |
| 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 1         | IN     |
| 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 2         | OUT    |
| 2018-02-01 01:00:00 | 1         | OUT    |
| 2018-02-01 01:00:00 | 2         | IN     |
```

The second table stores the code name of the object in a certain month.

```
| MONTH_KEY           | SITE_ID   | NAME       |
|---------------------|-----------|------------|
| 2018-01-01          | 1         | Apple      |
| 2018-01-01          | 2         | HP         |
| 2018-02-01          | 1         | Samsung    |
| 2018-02-01          | 2         | Blackberry |
```

How correctly join this two table and return such result?

```
| TIME_KEY            | ID_OBJECT | STATUS | NAME       |
|---------------------|-----------|--------|------------|
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 1         | IN     | Apple      |
| 2018-01-01 00:00:00 | 2         | OUT    | HP         |
| 2018-01-01 01:00:00 | 1         | OUT    | Apple      |
| 2018-01-01 01:00:00 | 2         | IN     | HP         |
| 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 1         | IN     | Samsung    |
| 2018-02-01 00:00:00 | 2         | OUT    | Blackberry |
| 2018-02-01 01:00:00 | 1         | OUT    | Samsung    |
| 2018-02-01 01:00:00 | 2         | IN     | Blackberry |
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: SO is not a free coding service website.  Post your query.  If it doesn't work, we can help.

Answer (score 1):

You need `JOIN` & conversations :

```
SELECT T1.TIME_KEY, T1.ID_OBJECT, T1.STATUS, T2.NAME
FROM table1 T1 INNER JOIN
     table2 T2
     ON T1.ID_OBJECT = T2.SITE_ID AND 
        CAST(T2.MONTH_KEY  AS DATE) = CAST(T1.TIME_KEY AS DATE);
```

Comment: Hello! It seems to me that `CAST(T2.MONTH_KEY  AS DATE) = CAST(T1.TIME_KEY AS DATE)` statement is not correct in my case. Let me try to explain you. In my post you can notice just example. The first table stores hourly information about the status of the object which was collected for several years every month every hour. The second table contains information about the name of the object in a certain month. Month stored in the second table like this: `2018-01-01`, `2018-02-01`, `2018-03-01` e.t.c. As you can see first day of the month only.

Comment: Lets say in next situation when first table has such value `2018-01-02 03:00:00`  and second table has such value`2018-01-01` I can't join them with you code cause dates are different but in fact they are in the same month. I need join by year and month somehow. I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 1):

you can convert date to month and can join

```
 select t2.TIME_KEY,t1.ID_OBJECT,STATUS,NAME        
 FROM table1 t1 JOIN
 table2 t2 on month(t1.TIME_KEY)=month(t2.TIME_KEY)  and t1.ID_OBJECT=t2.SITE_ID
```

Comment: Hello! I can't convert date only to month. It's not correct. Let me try to explain you. In my post you can notice just example. The first table stores hourly information about the status of the object which was collected for several years every month. The second table contains information about the name of the object in a certain month. Unfortunately in your example, a lot of things not taken into account.

Comment: Lets say in next situation when first table has such value `2018-01-02 03:00:00` and second table has such value `2019-01-01` I can't join them with you code cause month are the same but year are different. I need join by year and month somehow. I hope you understand me.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a correlated subquery:

```
select t1.*,
       (select t2.name
        from table2 t2
        where t2.site_id = t1.object_id and
              t1.time_key >= t2.month_key
        order by t2.month_key desc
        limit 1
       ) as name
from table1 t1;
```

This will take the *most recent* name, even if it is not in the current month.  I am guessing that is desirable behavior.

Comment: @NurzhanNogerbek . . . What do you mean?  If you need for the result to be from the current month, that is can be adjusted in the correlation clause.  This seems like a reasonable approach, given the limited data supplied in the question.